# How to re-open socket.io after disconnecting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

After doing `socket.disonnect()` on the browser, I would like to reconnect. How can I do it ?

Comment: By again calling socket.connect();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right thing to do is

```
socket.socket.disonnect()
```

then

```
socket.socket.reconnect()
```